# Flask view to handle Stripe request can't find stripeToken

Tags: python, flask, stripe-payments

I am trying to integrate Stripe with Flask, but the following error appears as soon as the page loads.

```
The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
```

Why am I getting this error and how do I fix it?

```
@store.route('/payment',methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def payment():
    stripe.api_key = "test_key"
    token = request.form['stripeToken']

    try:
        charge = stripe.Charge.create(
            amount=1000,
            currency="cad",
            source=token,
            description="Example charge"
        )
    except stripe.error.CardError, e:
        pass

    return render_template("payment_form.html")
```

```javascript
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    Stripe.setPublishableKey('test_key');

    jQuery(function($) {
        $('#payment-form').submit(function(event) {
            var $form = $(this);
            $form.find('button').prop('disabled', true);
            Stripe.card.createToken($form, stripeResponseHandler);
            return false;
        });
    });

    function stripeResponseHandler(status, response) {
        var $form = $('#payment-form');

        if (response.error) {
            $form.find('.payment-errors').text(response.error.message);
            $form.find('button').prop('disabled', false);
        } else {
            var token = response.id;
            $form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken" />').val(token));
            $form.get(0).submit();
        }
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this fails as soon as the page loads is because loading the page is a `GET` request.  `request.form` is filled on a `POST` request, which only occurs when you submit the form.  `request.form` is a special dictionary that raises a 400 error instead of a `KeyError`.

Only handle the form data during a `POST` request.  Also remember to redirect after `POST` so that the browser doesn't hang on to stale form data.

```
from flask import request, redirect, flash, render_template

stripe.api_key = 'test_key'

@store.route('/payment', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def payment():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        token = request.form['stripeToken']

        try:
            charge = stripe.Charge.create(amount=1000, currency="cad", source=token, description="Example charge")
            return redirect(request.path)
        except stripe.error.CardError, e:
            flash('Error processing payment.', 'error')

    return render_template('payment_form.html')
```

---

You will find it a lot easier to debug app errors if you **enable debug mode during development**: `app.run('localhost', debug=True)`.  This will provide you an interactive traceback debugger in the browswer when app errors occur.

Answer (score 0):

You want `request.form.get('stripeToken', None)`

Comment: I get the `The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand` error now

Comment: What server are you using? What browser are you using?

Comment: What do you mean by server? I am using chrome

Comment: How are you serving your application? Are you using the Flask development server (via app.run()) or uWSGI or Apache or similar?

Comment: Flask development server

Comment: Can you offer any more context on the error? Is there a stack trace or does the server just deliver that single line of text?

Comment: I get that single line of text

Comment: Here is what I see in the terminal: `127.0.0.1 - - [17/Jul/2015 11:27:09] "GET /store/payment HTTP/1.1" 400 -`

Comment: Are you certain that `stripeToken` has been given a value and added to your form before it is submitted? It looks like Flask will return 400 if `request.form[key]` raises KeyError

Comment: What happens if you `return repr(request.form)` as the first line in `payment`?

Comment: ImmutableMultiDict([])

Comment: Well there is your answer. The `stripeToken` value isn't even getting to the server. If it were, you would see `stripeToken` as a key under the ImmutableMultiDict.

Comment: What would I have to change? Most, if not all of the code is coming from the stripe tutorials

Comment: The reason it's not getting to the server is that it is being sent when the user clicks submit on the form, but I the page doesn't render and I get the error as seen above. If I were to be able to have access to the form, then submit, then I would see the token being sent to the server

Comment: Try replacing `$form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken" />').val(token));` with `$('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken" />').attr('value', token).appendTo($form);`

Comment: I got the same error, didn't seem to change anything

Comment: Well then this is a JavaScript problem. I suggest that you create a new question with a jQuery/JavaScript tag regarding the issue of adding a field to a form before submission.